# Adding music types to Noise library

Tags: music

I am a fan of video game music, and have some files in .vgm format. I place these files in my Music folder along with .mp3 files. While the mp3 files show up in the Noise library, the .vgm files don't. Is there currently any way I can add the .vgm files to the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supported content types are defined in the source code found [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-apps/noise/master/view/head:/core/Resources.vala). In other words, the only way to add additional file types to the library is to download the source code, edit it then build it myself.